# different SSL Ports running on nginx ssl preread module

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I hope some one can help. I'm running the nginx ssl_preread modul, so I can forward the ssl request to the backend servers over nginx reverse proxy. The nginx ssl_preread module was implemented, because I don't want to break the certificate. the reverse proxy acts as an "stupid" forwarder. However I've configured another ssl port (9098), other than the standard 443. The point ist that I cannot see in the access or error logs, if this port is called. I made a netstat -tulpen, and the Port 9098 ist listening. so I disabled the 443 and used the 9098 port and requests are still going to the Port 443. So what is wrong with that?

Thanks Haydar

```
            # configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
            user www-data;
            worker_processes auto;
            pid /run/nginx.pid;
            include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

            events {
                    # worker_connections 768;
                     worker_connections  1024;
                     multi_accept on;
                     use  epoll;
            }



            http {
                    ##
                    # Basic Settings
                    ##

                    sendfile on;
                    tcp_nopush on;
                    tcp_nodelay on;
                    keepalive_timeout 65;
                    types_hash_max_size 2048;
                    server_tokens off;

                    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
                    # server_name_in_redirect off;

                    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                    default_type application/octet-stream;

                    ##
                    # SSL Settings
                    ##

                    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
                    # ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
                    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

                    ##
                    # Logging Settings
                    ##

             log_format main 'site="$server_name" server="$host" dest_port="$server_port" dest_ip="$server_addr" '
                               'src="$remote_addr" src_ip="$realip_remote_addr" upstream_ip="$upstream_addr" "user="$remote_user" '
                               'time_local="$time_local" protocol="$server_protocol" status="$status" '
                               'bytes_out="$body_bytes_sent" bytes_in="$upstream_response_length" '
                               'http_referer="$http_referer" http_user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
                               'nginx_version="$nginx_version" http_x_forwarded_for="$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                               'http_x_header="$http_x_header" uri_query="$query_string" uri_path="$uri" '
                               'http_method="$request_method" response_time="$upstream_response_time" '
                               'cookie="$http_cookie" request_time="$request_time" ';

                    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
                    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

                    ##
                    # Gzip Settings
                    ##

                     gzip on;
                     gzip_vary on;
                     gzip_proxied any;
                     gzip_comp_level 6;
                    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
                    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
                     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

                    ##
                    # Virtual Host Configs
                    ##

                    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
                    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
            }

                    stream {

             include /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/*.conf;

            }




            #mail {
            #       # See sample authentication script at:
            #       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
            #
            #       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
            #       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
            #       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
            #
            #       server {
            #               listen     localhost:110;
            #               protocol   pop3;
            #               proxy      on;
            #       }
            #
            #       server {
            #               listen     localhost:143;
            #               protocol   imap;
            #               proxy      on;
            #       }
            #}

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
            load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
            load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
            load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
            load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
            load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

            types {
                text/html                             html htm shtml;
                text/css                              css;
                text/xml                              xml;
                image/gif                             gif;
                image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
                application/javascript                js;
                application/atom+xml                  atom;
                application/rss+xml                   rss;

                text/mathml                           mml;
                text/plain                            txt;
                text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
                text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
                text/x-component                      htc;

                image/png                             png;
                image/tiff                            tif tiff;
                image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
                image/x-icon                          ico;
                image/x-jng                           jng;
                image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
                image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
                image/webp                            webp;

                application/font-woff                 woff;
                application/java-archive              jar war ear;
                application/json                      json;
                application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
                application/msword                    doc;
                application/pdf                       pdf;
                application/postscript                ps eps ai;
                application/rtf                       rtf;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
                application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
                application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
                application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
                application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
                application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
                application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
                application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
                application/x-cocoa                   cco;
                application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
                application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
                application/x-makeself                run;
                application/x-perl                    pl pm;
                application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
                application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
                application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
                application/x-sea                     sea;
                application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
                application/x-stuffit                 sit;
                application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
                application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
                application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
                application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
                application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
                application/zip                       zip;

                application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
                application/octet-stream              deb;
                application/octet-stream              dmg;
                application/octet-stream              iso img;
                application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

                application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
                application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
                application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

                audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
                audio/mpeg                            mp3;
                audio/ogg                             ogg;
                audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
                audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

                video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
                video/mp2t                            ts;
                video/mp4                             mp4;
                video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
                video/quicktime                       mov;
                video/webm                            webm;
                video/x-flv                           flv;
                video/x-m4v                           m4v;
                video/x-mng                           mng;
                video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
                video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
                video/x-msvideo                       avi;
            }

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/optimize.conf:
                    ##
                    # Advanced Settings
                    ##

                    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
                    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
                    client_max_body_size 1G;
                    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

                    ##
                    # Buffering
                    ##

                    proxy_buffering    off;
                    proxy_buffer_size  128k;
                    proxy_buffers 100  128k;


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ara.conf:
            server {
              server_name hosting.domainname.com;
             listen 80;

              location ~ {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.20;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect off;
              }
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flamingo.conf:
            server {
              server_name projects03.domainname.com;
              listen 80;

              location ~ {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.17;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect off;
              }

            }

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fuchs.conf:
            server {
              server_name projects02.domainname.com;
              listen 80;

              location ~ {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.18;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect off;
              }
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pfau.conf:
            server {
              server_name  projects01.domainname.com;

             listen 80;

              location ~ {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.21;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect off;
              }
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/puffin.conf:
            server {
              server_name demo.domainname.com;

            listen 80;

              location ~ {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.14;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect off;
              }
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tukan.conf:
            server {
              server_name  demo2.domainname.com;

             listen 80;

              location ~ {
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.13;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect off;
              }
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/00_prefix.conf:
            ## mapping of servers to upstream servers ###
            ## In this section, we have to pair frontend and backend servers
            #  everytime we want have them reverse proxied
            ## e.g. <relaserver.domainname>:port   <backendservervariable_port>

             map $ssl_preread_server_name:$server_port $upstream {
             #######
             projects03.domainname.com:443 flamingo_backend_443;
             #######
             projects02.domainname.com:443 fuchs_backend_443;
             #######
             projects01.domainname.com:443 pfau_backend_443;
             #######
             hosting.domainname.com:443 ara_backend_443;
             #######
             demo.domainname.com:443 puffin_backend_443;
             demo.domainname.com:9098 puffin_backend_9098;
             #######
             demo2.domainname.com:443 tukan_backend_443;
            }


            log_format  main '$remote_addr [$time_local] $remote_port '
                             '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                             '$session_time "$upstream_addr" '
                             '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';



            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/01_demo.domainname.com.conf:
            upstream puffin_backend_443 {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server 192.168.1.14:443;
            }

             server {
               listen 9098;
               proxy_pass $upstream;
               ssl_preread on;
             }

            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/02_projects03.domainname.com.conf:
            # 02_projects03.domainname.com
            upstream  flamingo_backend_443 {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server 192.168.1.17:443;
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/03_projects02.domainname.com.conf:
            # 03_projects02.domainname.com
            upstream  fuchs_backend_443 {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server 192.168.1.18:443;
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/04_projects01.domainname.com.conf:
            # 04_projects01.domainname.com
            upstream  pfau_backend_443 {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server 192.168.1.21:443;
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/05_hosting.domainname.com.conf:
            # 05_hosting.domainname.com
            upstream  ara_backend_443 {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server 192.168.1.20:443;
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/06_demo2.domainname.com.conf:
            # 06_demo2.domainname.com
            upstream  tukan_backend_443 {
              hash $remote_addr consistent;
              server 192.168.1.13:443;
            }


            # configuration file /etc/nginx/stream/enabled/99_suffix.conf:
            server {
              listen 443;
              proxy_pass $upstream;
              ssl_preread on;
            }
```

Comment: Please can you share the output of `nginx -T`

Comment: attached you'll find the output. as I've said 443 work fine. But, when I call a link in the website which has a Port of 9098(e.g. https://demo.domainname.com/.../.../somelink.xml, it redirects me still to 443 or shows me nothing. Port 9098 is not blocked in the firewall

Comment: Maybe because you check for `$ssl_preread_server_name:$server_port`  and not only for `$ssl_preread_server_name` I would suggest to change the `map $ssl_preread_server_name:$server_port $upstream {` to `map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {` as shown in the doc [Module ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html)

Comment: Well this didn't work, however, I've all configuration in the stream directive in one file. After that, I could see Port 9098 was handled and forwarded to the backend. Rgds Haydar. Thansk for the help anyway